# <nav> elements in a <footer> element

Tags: html, css

I'm just getting started on using HTML5 display elements (header, footer, nav etc.) and was reading in specific about the nav element when I came across this in the HTML5 spec:

> Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — the
>   element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major
>   navigation blocks. In particular, **it is common for footers to have a
>   short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of
>   service, the home page, and a copyright page. The footer element alone
>   is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such
>   cases, it is usually unnecessary.**

Why specifically can nav elements not be used in a footer? More often than not sites seem to have a substantial navigation menu in their footer (take StackOverflow for example, it has a bigger nav in it's footer than header!)

And if I do include a nav element in a footer will my site fail HTML5 validation? Or is this just a recommendation that W3C are making?

Comment: You've answered your own question if you just re-read your post. "The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element **can be used in such cases**, it is usually unnecessary."

Comment: And as far as failing validation I highly doubt that would happen, but why don't you simply test it in a HTML5 validator?

Comment: another case of me not reading things properly, sorry :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the text again, it does **NOT** say that it's not allowed, just that it's **not recommended**.

As for the reason I can only speculate: these new elements have been introduced for semantic reasons and if you follow this recommendation you are giving more value to the main nav element (i think SEO).